# primefaces select tab when button is clicked

Tags: html, primefaces, tabs

I assume this is a rather simple issue, but I'm very new to Primefaces. I have a form that's including a few Primefaces tabs. Naturally I can view each tab when I click on it, but I'm looking for a way to go to a certain tab when a commandButton is clicked. Is there any way to do this?

Basically I'm looking for something like:

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit"
                onclick="<open a certain tab>"
                action="#{doSomeJavaWork}"
                update=":main_tabs:some_form" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try Primeface Wizard http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:commandButton ... onclick="tabViewWidgetVar.selectTab(2);" .../>
```